# Two instances contain same values

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm running into a bizarre bug while trying to create a Dictionary object.  Pretty basic stuff. However when I create 2 instances of the object, and then set some values on one, they appear on both.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
function Dict() { }

Dict.prototype = {

  items: { },

  prop: function(key) {
    return ':' + key;
  },

  get: function(key, def) {
    var p = this.prop(key),
        k = this.items;

    return k.hasOwnProperty(p) ? k[p] : def;
  },

  set: function(key, value) {
    var p = this.prop(key);

    this.items[p] = value;

    return value;
  },

  count: function() {
    return Object.keys(this.items).length;
  },

  has: function(key) {
    var p = this.prop(key);

    return this.items.hasOwnProperty(p);
  },

  del: function(key) {
    var p = this.prop(key),
        k = this.items;

    if(k.hasOwnProperty(p))
      delete k[p];
  },

  keys: function() {
    return Object.keys(this.items).map(function(key) {
      return key.substring(1);
    });
  }
};

var a = new Dict();
var b = new Dict();

a.set('foo', 'bar');

console.log(a.keys());
console.log(b.keys());
```

Comment: Objects on the prototype are shared between all instances

Comment: [this article](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/05/17/forcing-a-constructor-in-javascript/) about forcing proper usage of constructors may be of interest to you if you personally are not the only consumer of your code (or if you just dont trust yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `items` property is set on the `prototype`. The prototype is not cloned when creating an object, so `items` is the same on the two `Dict`s. Set `items` in the constructor so each object has its own:

```
function Dict() {
    this.items = {};
}
```

Prototypes work because when you try to access an object's property, it first checks the object's own properties to see if it contains it. If so, that's the value. If it's not found there, it checks the prototype. If it's not there, it continues traversing the chain of prototypes until it finds the property. If it's still not found, it results in `undefined`. (for more detail, [see the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x4.2.1))

Comment: > The prototype is not cloned when creating an object

Comment: And just when I thought I understood prototypes. Uh!

Comment: @Matthew: I added a little more detail about how prototypes *actually* work.

Answer (score 5):

You're defining `items` inside your prototype which means it will be shared by all instances. You need to set it inside the "constructor" function and remove it from the prototype.

```
function Dict() { this.items = []; }
```

I've created a JS Fiddle for you with the full source code at http://jsfiddle.net/brunomsilva/zaSY2/.

Answer (score 2):

to define a class to use, try moving the function definitions to the prototype without replacing the prototype object, like so:

```
     function Dict() {
        this.items = {};
     }
     Dict.prototype.prop = function (key) {
         return ':' + key;
     };
     Dict.prototype.get = function (key, def) {
         var p = this.prop(key),
    k = this.items;

         return k.hasOwnProperty(p) ? k[p] : def;
     };
     Dict.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
         var p = this.prop(key);

         this.items[p] = value;

         return value;
     };
     Dict.prototype.count = function () {
         return Object.keys(this.items).length;
     };
     Dict.prototype.has =function (key) {
            var p = this.prop(key);

            return this.items.hasOwnProperty(p);
        };
     Dict.prototype.del =function (key) {
            var p = this.prop(key),
    k = this.items;

            if (k.hasOwnProperty(p))
                delete k[p];
        };
     Dict.prototype.keys = function () {
            return Object.keys(this.items).map(function (key) {
                return key.substring(1);
            });
        };
```